# Using a C++-function that is exported

Tags: c++, import, include, export

I have been googling for days now, and I cant seem to wrap my head around this problem.

I have a header, which exports some functions to a library. This file is called test_extern.h, and the function looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int aFunction(int a, int b);
```

I have two other files, one .h and .cpp which calculates some things with the help of the exported file. I have stripped down the versions to show what I want to do.

A.h file:

```
// Include CBaseDILI_J1939 header file.
class A : public CBaseDILI_J1939
{
public:
  int bFunction(int a, int b);
}
```

A.cpp file:

```
#include "test_extern.h"
#include "A.h"

int A::bFunction(int a, int b) {
  return aFunction(a, b);  // REturn the value of the exported function!
}
```

Now when I run this, I get "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_aFunction".

I have read and read all there is about exporting dll's, is there anyone who knows what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What library file(s) are you specifying when you run the linker?

Comment: I dont add anything extra to the linker. Do I have to do that? I just supposed that the linker would find it

Comment: So, is A in a different project to aFunction? In that case the declaration from the header isn't enough. Do you have a lib from the dll or not?

Comment: @Karadur solved it! I had forgotten to import the functions before I used them. Easy fix, but oh so hard to find when you've been staring at the code for hours ;)

Comment: @JerryCoffin You were right. I had too specify the .lib file when I rebuilded the solution, or the linker wouldn't find my functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the dll function in the calling module as dllspec(dllimport).

Comment: Thank you so much! Haha, so simple, but yet so hard to find!

Answer (score 2):

@Karadur is right.

Check the example on this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx.
The answer is on the bottom of this page.

In A.cpp add this on top.

`__declspec(dllimport) int aFunction(int a, int b);`

Comment: Do not forget to check msdn, you will find a lot of helpful posts for windows development. Despite the fact I don't like MS and that I don't develop a lot on their platforms. Their support is by far one of the best...